# Using local variable inside dynamic SQL does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

This static query using a parameter returns one row:

```
DECLARE @sqltext nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @status varchar(100)
SET @status = 'Active: Complete'

select * from status where StatusTitle = @status and type_id = 800
```

---

However, using the parameter in a dynamic SQL query as follows does not return any rows at all:

```
SET @sqltext = 'SELECT s.StatusID
FROM   [Status] s
WHERE  (
( s.StatusTitle ='' + @status + '' )
AND s.[type_id] = 800  )'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqltext
```

I know there is something wrong with the WHERE clause. I can't figure out how to correct it.

Comment: add `AND s.[type_id] = 800` to the first static SQL and check if it still returns 1 row

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to format the `@status` into the statement. Executing a statement using `sp_executesql` creates a new scope and local variables from another scope will not be visible.

In your statement you can remedy this by adding extra quotes around `@status`. But to guard against SQL injection, you first need to replace single quotes with two single quotes in `@status`.

```
SET @status=REPLACE(@status,'''','''''');
SET @sqltext = 'SELECT s.StatusID
FROM   [Status] s
WHERE  (
( s.StatusTitle =''' + @status + ''' )
AND s.[type_id] = 800  )'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqltext;
```

Better still is to supply `sp_executesql` with an INPUT parameter. That way there's no need for the extra quotes and stuff, and protection against SQL Injection is guaranteed this way.

```
SET @sqltext = 'SELECT s.StatusID
FROM   [Status] s
WHERE  (
( s.StatusTitle = @status )
AND s.[type_id] = 800  )'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqltext, N'@status VARCHAR(100)', @status;
```

Comment: In case you have more than one parameter, you may find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/28481277

Answer (score 3):

this will also save you from sql injection

```
DECLARE @sqltext nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @status varchar(100)
SET @status = 'Active: Complete'
SET @sqltext = 'SELECT s.StatusID
FROM   [Status] s
WHERE  (
( s.StatusTitle = @status )
AND s.[type_id] = 800  )'

DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(99)
SET @params = '@status nvarchar(99)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqltext, @params, @status
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a pair of single quotes in your query so your query should be something like

```
SET @sqltext = 'SELECT s.StatusID
FROM   [Status] s
WHERE  (
( s.StatusTitle =''' + @status + ''' )
AND s.[type_id] = 800  )'

EXECUTE(@sqltext)
```

If you are using execute sp_executesql(Forced Statement Caching) then you have to use the following query

```
SET @sqltext = 'SELECT s.StatusID
FROM   [Status] s
WHERE  (
( s.StatusTitle = @status )
AND s.[type_id] = 800  )'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqltext, N'@status NVARCHAR(100)', @status;
```

best practice is use sp_executesql then you can restrict sql injections

**Note :**

Advantages of sp_executesql

1.Allows for statements to be parameterized.

2.Has strongly typed variables/parameters – and this can reduce injection and offer some performance benefits!

3.Creates a plan on first execution (similar to stored procedures) and subsequent executions reuse this plan

Note 2 : The question already has  working answers, and I hope using execute also a method and none of the answers mentioned that so I have included that too in my answer

Comment: @TT. ow sorry, i had updated , thanks for correction

Comment: @TT. yes i have seen an  already existing answer, but i hope execute is also an option and none of the answer specifies that , thats why i have included an ans with that option