# I am getting a "Incorrect syntax near '1'." error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My C# code is pasted below:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=pawan-pc;Initial Catalog=App91;Integrated Security=True");
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_gettinglogsfromdevice", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename","DeviceLogs_"+comboBox_Attendance_SelMonth.Text+"_"+combobox_Attendance_SelectYear.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromduration",datetimepicker_att_From.Value.Date);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Toduration",datetimepicker_att_To.Value.Date);

    DataRowView drow = (DataRowView)combobox_att_events.SelectedValue;
    string l = drow.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();


    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd1.Connection = con;
    con.Open();


    cmd1.CommandText = "select WorkCode from WorkCodes where WorkCodeName='"+l+"'";
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

    dk = new DataTable();
    dk.Load(reader);



    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkCode", dk.Rows[0][0]);

    SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dp =new DataTable();
    dp.Load(reader1);

    datagridview_att_attendance.DataSource=dp;
```

The referenced stored procedure is pasted below:

```
create procedure sp_gettinglogsfromdevice
(
    @tablename varchar(75),
    @fromduration datetime,
    @Toduration datetime,
    @WorkCode nvarchar(100)
)
As
Begin
Exec('select UserId,LogDate,WorkCode from '
    +@tablename+' where LogDate between '
    +@fromduration+' and '+@Toduration+' and WorkCode = '+@WorkCode);
End
Go
```

Iam actually taking the name of the table dynamically as in my database a table is created automatically with the name DeviceLogs_(month)_(year) for every month of logs that are created.Please help me with this error.I have seen numerous post but i cannot seem to wrap my head along this idea

Comment: Which SQL command is resulting in this error?  What is the exact SQL code being executed in that command?

Comment: You need quotes around your dates if you are going to execute it like that. But your code, as is, is open to SQL Injection. You should use `sp_executesql` instead.

Comment: @David looks like the `exec` line the concatenation of that datetime and the string would break the sql.

Comment: 1. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks (Your stored procedure as well). 2. Don't use `sp_` as a prefix for stored procedre names. this prefix is used by microsoft. use `stp_` if you must use a prefix. 3. Don't share all the code. We are only interested in the relevant part.

Comment: @mjwills to add, `QUOTENAME(@tablename)` would probably be a good idea as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EXEC sp\_executesql with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481189/exec-sp-executesql-with-multiple-parameters)

Comment: I have posted the stored procedure above.The Execution breaks at this sentence stating the error

Comment: @ZoharPeled first time I see someone complaining about to much code :)

Comment: @mjwills but the OP does not use `sp_executesql`... I know, he should ;-)

Comment: SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: @RandRandom I actually complain about it a lot... :-)

Comment: Don't Worry its a windows form application.Its not on the net.Can you guys please tell me what's causing this error.I will amend my code to use the appropriate ways lator

Comment: Pawan, read  mjwills comments or my previous comment

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of "this is internal so I can code it sloppy because nobody will do anything malicious". This is a pattern I have seen too many times. First of all you are still prone to sql injection, just not as likely. Secondly, this program could be converted to a website at some point. Third, if you do write an externally facing application somebody may use this code as an example and now the lazy coding done here is suddenly exposed externally. Just use parameters...they are so simple to use.

Comment: OK bro, will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Exec('select UserId,LogDate,WorkCode from '
+@tablename+' where LogDate between '
+@fromduration+' and '+@Toduration+' and WorkCode = '+@WorkCode);
```

should be changed to:

```
declare @statement nvarchar(4000)

set @statement = N'select UserId,LogDate,WorkCode from '
    +@tablename+' where LogDate between @fromduration and @Toduration and WorkCode = @WorkCode'

EXEC sp_executesql  @statement,N'@fromduration datetime, @Toduration datetime, @WorkCode nvarchar(100)', @fromduration, @Toduration, @WorkCode;
```

To ensure that the dates and work code are passed correctly.

Comment: Yes, but nobody has noticed the first error is before even attempting to execute the stored procedure.

Comment: Well, OK I guess I can't be sure. It looked to me like OP got 1 confused with l but now maybe not. Apologies.

Comment: The 1 is likely because the date starts with a 1 @Crowcoder . The query he is trying to execute is something like `select UserId,LogDate,WorkCode from TableName where LogDate between 1/1/2000` etc.

Comment: Yes, the problem is with `'`, but your answer with `sp_executesql` is much better and can be faster. +1

Comment: Must declare the scalar variable "@Toduration".

Comment: Dude That worked,Thank you so much.I know i got lot to learn,Iam just beginning.Will stay in touch thanks