# Concatenate query string in procedure having case statement with parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to append below select query set with another set query based on condition

```
    DECLARE @queryString VARCHAR(1000);
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Set @queryString ='SELECT 
                CASE 
                                WHEN d.sno IS NOT NULL THEN 'y'
                                ELSE NULL 
                END 
                amendment_type, 
                u.user_login_id [User], 
                role_name [Role], 
                u.user_name [Name], 
                a.companyname        +':<br>('+b.branch+')' [Agent/Branch], 
                u.last_login_pc+'('+u.ip_address+')<br> Login Time: '+cast(u.last_login AS varchar(50)) [Last Login], 
                u.lock_status [Lock/Unlock], 

                CASE 
                                WHEN u.lock_status='y' THEN 'Locked - '+ u.lock_by
                                WHEN datediff(d,u.last_login,getdate())>u.lock_days 
                                AND             isnull(u.lock_days,0)>0 THEN 'Locked - Day Exceed'
                                WHEN u.active_session IS NULL 
                                AND             isnull(u.lock_status,'n')='n' THEN 'Not Login'
                                ELSE 'Active'
                END 
                [Status], 
                u.*, 
                a.agentcan, 
                b.branch, 
                b.branchcodechar, 
                NULL branchcan
FROM            agentsub u 
JOIN            agentbranchdetail b 
ON              u.agent_branch_code=b.agent_branch_code 
JOIN            agentdetail a 
ON              b.agentcode=a.agentcode
LEFT OUTER JOIN application_role_agent_user r 
ON              u.user_login_id=r.user_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN application_role p 
ON              r.role_id=p.role_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN agentsub_amendment d 
ON              d.agent_user_id=u.agent_user_id
WHERE           1=1'

IF (@loginId !=null)
BEGIN
 SET @queryString =@queryString + 'and u.user_login_id like ('+ @loginId +')'
END


SET @queryString =@queryString +'order by u.user_login_id,a.companyname,b.branch'

EXEC @queryString
```

Comment: *Don't* concatenate anything. Create a view with the query (except the `WHERE 1=1` part). After that you can easily create queries on top of that view and probably won't need a stored procedure at all.

Comment: we are not using views.. store procedure is mandatory.

Comment: Use views then and query them from one or two stored procedures - one for all resutls, one for filtered results. The syntax coloring alone should show you that the query contains a lot of single quotes that result in a bad string. Do the people that mandate stored procedures also mandate that there should be sql script errors, conversion problems and SQL injection attacks?

Comment: If you really don't want vies (*why?*), you can still create two separate stored procedures, one with the unfiltered query, on with the filtered query. Using views avoids both errors and code duplication though

Answer (score 0):

First... Your query as it stands (via notepad++) is 1,731 characters, so it wont fit into a varchar(1000)

Second... You need to address some escaping issues with your query; e.g.

```
WHEN d.sno IS NOT NULL THEN 'y'
```

should probably be

```
WHEN d.sno IS NOT NULL THEN ''y''
```

Third... google/investigate sp_executesql and parameters

Finally... as @Panagiotis Kanavos says, *Don't* concatenate anything (see Third...); you need to look up "sql injection"

Answer (score 0):

@uberbloke is correct regarding query length.

[EXEC sp_executesql with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28481277/7009448) link give you solution for `dynamic query` to `pass parameter values`.

Please check below updated query code.

```
DECLARE @queryString NVARCHAR(MAX);

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
Set @queryString =
    'SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN d.sno IS NOT NULL THEN ''y''
            ELSE NULL 
        END 
        amendment_type, 
        u.user_login_id [User], 
        role_name [Role], 
        u.user_name [Name], 
        a.companyname + '':<br>('' + b.branch) [Agent/Branch], 
        u.last_login_pc + ''('' + u.ip_address + '')<br> Login Time: '' + cast(u.last_login AS varchar(50)) + '' [Last Login], 
        u.lock_status [Lock/Unlock], 
        CASE 
            WHEN u.lock_status = ''y'' THEN ''Locked - '' + u.lock_by
            WHEN datediff(d,u.last_login,getdate()) > u.lock_days AND (u.lock_days,0) > 0 THEN ''Locked - Day Exceed''
            WHEN u.active_session IS NULL AND isnull(u.lock_status,''n'') = ''n'' THEN ''Not Login''
            ELSE ''Active''
        END [Status], 
        u.*, 
        a.agentcan, 
        b.branch, 
        b.branchcodechar, 
        NULL branchcan
    FROM agentsub u 
    JOIN agentbranchdetail b ON u.agent_branch_code = b.agent_branch_code 
    JOIN agentdetail a ON b.agentcode = a.agentcode
    LEFT OUTER JOIN application_role_agent_user r ON u.user_login_id = r.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN application_role p ON r.role_id = p.role_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN agentsub_amendment d ON d.agent_user_id = u.agent_user_id
    WHERE 1 = 1 '

IF (@loginId !=null)
BEGIN
    SET @queryString = @queryString + 'and u.user_login_id like ('+ @loginId + ')'
END

SET @queryString = @queryString + ' order by u.user_login_id,a.companyname,b.branch'

EXEC sp_executesql @queryString
```

I am getting below error:
[image]

Comment: getting error on procedure execution.
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '
       END [Status],
       u.*,
       a.agentcan,
       b.branch,
       b.branchcodechar,
       NULL branchcan
   FROM agentsub u
   JOIN agentbranchdetail b ON u.agent_branch_code = b.agent_branch_code
   JOIN agentdetail a ON b.agentcode = a.agentcode
   LEFT OUTER JOIN application_role_agent_user r ON u.user_login_id = r.user_id