# Pass XML variable from a stored proc to another stored proc in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 stored proc.

The first one receive as input parameter some variables and one of them is XML.

Inside this proc i call another proc but dynamically like that. This proc handle the XML to insert it in the DB.

```
SET @SQL = 'EXEC [' + @ServerIp + '].[List_' + CAST(@AccountId AS VARCHAR) + '].[dbo].[psu_proc_name] @ParameterId = ' + CAST(@ParameterId AS VARCHAR) + ',@MappingFields = ' + @MappingFields
```

@MappingFields is the name of the XML variable in the first proc and also in the second proc (called dynamically)

I manage the treatment of the XML in the second proc (dynamic) but i don't know how to pass the parameter as XML to the second proc.

Thanks

Comment: Just a word of caution casting as varchar with a length can cause some heartache.

Comment: you mean "without" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) stored procedure instead of using the simle `exec` command. See the not duplicate, but very clear examples in the question [EXEC sp_executesql with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481189/exec-sp-executesql-with-multiple-parameters) for easy to understand details.

Answer (score 0):

i've tried something like that :

```
SET @SQL = N'EXEC [' + @ServerIp + '].[List_' + CAST(@AccountId AS VARCHAR) + '].[dbo].[psu_opensystem_field_mapping_add]'
EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL, N'@ParameterId INT, @MappingFields XML' , @ParameterId, @MappingFields
```

But it says that

```
Procedure or function 'psu_opensystem_field_mapping_add' expects parameter '@ParameterId', which was not supplied
```

Comment: Remove the EXEC statement from your SQL string. Your command should be `EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL, N'@ParameterId INT, @MappingFields XML' , @ParameterId, @MappingFields`, and the @SQL variable should contain `N'[' + @ServerIp + '].[List_' + CAST(@AccountId AS VARCHAR) + '].[dbo].[psu_opensystem_field_mapping_add]'