# Set Variable shows different result SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to do a stored procedure declaring variable and setting its values, but it shows different values compare to the one I set.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertAccount]
    @OldAccount AS VARCHAR(25),
    @NewAccount AS VARCHAR(25),
    @TableName AS VARCHAR(25)
AS
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @TableName_ sysname

    SET @OldAccount = '7006-0090-0280'
    SET @NewAccount ='5555-0090-0280'
    SET @TableName_ = 'cust'

    SELECT @NewAccount

    SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ', ', '') + Name 
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@TableName_)
      AND name NOT IN ('custnum');

    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT '+ @NewAccount+','+@OldAccount+',' + @SQL + ' FROM '   + @TableName_+' where custnum ='''+@OldAccount+''''
    EXEC (@SQL)
GO
```

[image]

Comment: Here is a hint:  `5555 - 90 - 280 = 5185` and `7006 - 90 - 280 = 6636`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips..Ohh it changed into a formula?...even though i declared it as varchar.... any solution you can offer?..Thanks

Comment: It's dynamic SQL, you don't have single quotes around it so it assumes it's math.  Basically you said `Select 5555 - 90 - 280` not `Select '5555-0090-0280'`.  That being said, it would be better to use a [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481189/exec-sp-executesql-with-multiple-parameters/28481277).

Comment: `SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT '''+ @NewAccount+''', '''+@OldAccount+''',' + @SQL + ' FROM ' + @TableName_+' where custnum ='''+@OldAccount+''''`

Comment: Got it now, Thanks..You can add your last comment on as answer. And ill upvote it Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dynamic query does not have quotes around the values, so the SQL standard response is to use math.

example

```sql
'SELECT '+ @NewAccount
```

yields

```sql
SELECT 5555 - 90 - 280
```

The correct way so to

```sql
SELECT ''' + @NewAccount + ''''
```

That being said, **you should be really careful with dynamic sql, allowing external sources to build their own query is asking for issues**.  One way to prevent some issues is to use [Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481189/exec-sp-executesql-with-multiple-parameters/28481277).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to `print(@sql)` this will give you.

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT '+ @NewAccount+','+@OldAccount+',' + @SQL + ' FROM ' + @TableName_+' where custnum ='''+@OldAccount+''''
print @SQL


SELECT 5555-0090-0280,7006-0090-0280, .... FROM tname_cust where custnum ='7006-0090-0280'
```

so its will give you the difference, not as string.

Change your last **@sql** statement to:

```
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT '''+ @NewAccount+''', '''+@OldAccount+''',' + @SQL + ' FROM ' + @TableName_+' where custnum ='''+@OldAccount+''''
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT '5555-0090-0280', '7006-0090-0280', .... FROM tname_cust where custnum ='7006-0090-0280'
```

To treat your `variables` as `string` not as arithmetic expression.